# Filtering/subsetting R dataframe based on each rows n'th position value

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a 'df' with 2 columns:

```
Combinations <- c(0011111111, 0011113111, 0013113112, 0022223114)
Values <- c(1,2,3,4)

df <- cbind.data.frame(Combinations, Values)
```

I am trying to find a way to subset or filter the dataframe where the 'Combinations' column's 7th, 8th, and 9th digits equal 311. For the example given, I would expect Combination's 001111**311**1, 001311**311**2, 002222**311**4

There are also instances where I would need to find different combinations, in different nth positions.

I know substring() can find these values for single rows but I'm not sure how to apply it to an entire dataframe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another base R idea:

```
Combinations <- c("0011111111", "0011113111", "0013113112", "0022223114")
Values <- c(1,2,3,4)
df <- data.frame(Combinations, Values)

df[grep(pattern = "^[0-9]{6}311.$", df$Combinations), ]
```

Output:

```
 Combinations Values
2   0011113111      2
3   0013113112      3
4   0022223114      4
```

As a tip, if you want to know more about regular expressions, this website helps me a lot: https://regexr.com/3elkd

Comment: Hi Paul, thanks for the link ... I plugged the expression into the link and I still don't quite get how it's working.. The 311 part is straightforward enough, but what's the [0-9] and {6}? Sorry, feels like I should know this..!

Comment: Hi @Birdman :) no problem, I also struggle to understand regular expression, this website is quite nice though because it explains the meaning when you hoover your mouse over statements. Here, [0-9] means "Matches character in the range 0 to 9", {6} means "match 6 of the preceding token" i.e it means "they are 6 numbers between 0 and 9".

Comment: Also `^` and `$` mean "this is where the string starts/ends". `.` means "match any character", note that `^[0-9]{6}311[0-9]$` seems to work too.

Comment: So using the same data, if I put in `df[grep(pattern = "^[0-9]{1}011.$", df$Combinations), ]` 

Then I would expect "0**011**111111", "0**011**113111" to be the resulting Combinations, as the preceding digit (token?) is a 0 (which is in the [0-9] range) and then the next 3 values are 011 -- I've misunderstood something, sorry again!

Comment: You are close, I think you will need `^[0-9]{1}011.{6}$` or `^[0-9]{1}011[0-9]{6}$` as a regular expression, all your string needs to be described. The `{}`are here to locate the pattern `311` or `011`

Comment: Thanks, I get it :). Answered.

Answer (score 3):

`subtring` will work with vectors as well.

```
subset(df, substring(Combinations, 7, 9) == 311)

#  Combinations Values
#2   0011113111      2
#3   0013113112      3
#4   0022223114      4
```

**data**

```
Combinations <- c("0011111111", "0011113111", "0013113112", "0022223114")
Values <- c(1,2,3,4)
df <- data.frame(Combinations, Values)
```

Answer (score 2):

Would this work?

```
library(dplyr)    
library(stringr)    
df %>% filter(str_sub(Combinations, 7,9) == 311)
  Combinations Values
1   0011113111      2
2   0013113112      3
3   0022223114      4
```

Answer (score 0):

Not pretty but works:

```
df[which(lapply(strsplit(df$Combinations, ""), function(x) which(x[7]==3 & x[8]==1 & x[9]==1))==1),]
  Combinations Values
2   0011113111      2
3   0013113112      3
4   0022223114      4
```

Data:

```
Combinations <- c("0011111111", "0011113111", "0013113112", "0022223114")
Values <- c(1,2,3,4)

df <- cbind.data.frame(Combinations, Values)
```